# Ingress Nginx with CrashLoopBackOff status using helm_release in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

When we are creating ingress-nginx using helm_release in terraform, we see that the pod is crashing as soon as it is running. This is the error logs

```
kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-b7b59d4cb-88x22 -n ingress-controller
a-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v0.48.1
  Build:         30809c066cd027079cbb32dccc8a101d6fbffdcb
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.20.1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I0926 12:46:17.684395       7 flags.go:211] "Watching for Ingress" class="nginx"
W0926 12:46:17.684465       7 flags.go:216] Ingresses with an empty class will also be processed by this Ingress controller
W0926 12:46:17.685114       7 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0926 12:46:17.685422       7 main.go:241] "Creating API client" host="https://172.20.0.1:443"
I0926 12:46:17.718879       7 main.go:285] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="23+" git="v1.23.10-eks-15b7512" state="clean" commit="cd6399691d9b1fed9ec20c9c5e82f5993c3f42cb" platform="linux/amd64"
I0926 12:46:18.259466       7 main.go:105] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I0926 12:46:18.263473       7 main.go:115] "Enabling new Ingress features available since Kubernetes v1.18"
W0926 12:46:18.265424       7 main.go:127] No IngressClass resource with name nginx found. Only annotation will be used.
I0926 12:46:18.281257       7 ssl.go:532] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0926 12:46:18.316017       7 nginx.go:254] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I0926 12:46:18.331965       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-controller", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"cd2b9444-93e6-40f4-93df-d78d521df150", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"251240", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-controller/ingress-nginx-controller
E0926 12:46:19.420220       7 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource
E0926 12:46:20.570408       7 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource
E0926 12:46:23.707451       7 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource
E0926 12:46:29.815028       7 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource
E0926 12:46:38.157386       7 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource
E0926 12:46:52.853581       7 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Ingress: failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource
I0926 12:47:16.370685       7 main.go:187] "Received SIGTERM, shutting down"
I0926 12:47:16.370771       7 nginx.go:372] "Shutting down controller queues"
E0926 12:47:16.371073       7 store.go:178] timed out waiting for caches to sync
I0926 12:47:16.371124       7 nginx.go:296] "Starting NGINX process"
I0926 12:47:16.371603       7 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-controller/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0926 12:47:16.372263       7 queue.go:78] "queue has been shutdown, failed to enqueue" key="&ObjectMeta{Name:initial-sync,GenerateName:,Namespace:,SelfLink:,UID:,ResourceVersion:,Generation:0,CreationTimestamp:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,DeletionTimestamp:<nil>,DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:nil,Labels:map[string]string{},Annotations:map[string]string{},OwnerReferences:[]OwnerReference{},Finalizers:[],ClusterName:,ManagedFields:[]ManagedFieldsEntry{},}"
I0926 12:47:16.372312       7 nginx.go:316] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0926 12:47:16.397847       7 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-b7b59d4cb-p82hf"
I0926 12:47:16.408516       7 status.go:132] "removing value from ingress status" address=[afe109b0d5aa3428dbfee84aa8855cfa-d3a6adbf32d90e27.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com]
I0926 12:47:16.408586       7 nginx.go:380] "Stopping admission controller"
I0926 12:47:16.408698       7 nginx.go:388] "Stopping NGINX process"
E0926 12:47:16.408774       7 nginx.go:319] "Error listening for TLS connections" err="http: Server closed"
2022/09/26 12:47:16 [notice] 39#39: signal process started
I0926 12:47:17.414278       7 nginx.go:401] "NGINX process has stopped"
I0926 12:47:17.414295       7 main.go:195] "Handled quit, awaiting Pod deletion"
I0926 12:47:27.414421       7 main.go:198] "Exiting" code=0
```

```
❯ kubectl describe pod ingress-nginx-controller-b7b59d4cb-hfsxg -n ingress-controller
Name:         ingress-nginx-controller-b7b59d4cb-hfsxg
Namespace:    ingress-controller
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-10-0-0-63.ec2.internal/10.0.0.63
Start Time:   Tue, 27 Sep 2022 17:31:38 +0530
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
              pod-template-hash=b7b59d4cb
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Running
IP:           10.0.0.235
IPs:
  IP:           10.0.0.235
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/ingress-nginx-controller-b7b59d4cb
Containers:
  controller:
    Container ID:  docker://816776d9c777d62d4e4973dc18b305100b50fc6cb0824b6452d2cd8c9b413d27
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.48.1@sha256:e9fb216ace49dfa4a5983b183067e97496e7a8b307d2093f4278cd550c303899
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:e9fb216ace49dfa4a5983b183067e97496e7a8b307d2093f4278cd550c303899
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP, 8443/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
      --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
      --ingress-class=nginx
      --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
      --validating-webhook=:8443
      --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
      --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 27 Sep 2022 17:34:00 +0530
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 27 Sep 2022 17:32:50 +0530
      Finished:     Tue, 27 Sep 2022 17:34:00 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   90Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:  http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       ingress-nginx-controller-b7b59d4cb-hfsxg (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  ingress-controller (v1:metadata.namespace)
      LD_PRELOAD:     /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
    Mounts:
      /usr/local/certificates/ from webhook-cert (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-z842g (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  webhook-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  ingress-nginx-admission
    Optional:    false
  kube-api-access-z842g:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  3m32s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ingress-controller/ingress-nginx-controller-b7b59d4cb-hfsxg to ip-10-0-0-63.ec2.internal
  Normal   Pulling    3m31s                  kubelet            Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.48.1@sha256:e9fb216ace49dfa4a5983b183067e97496e7a8b307d2093f4278cd550c303899"
  Normal   Pulled     3m26s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.48.1@sha256:e9fb216ace49dfa4a5983b183067e97496e7a8b307d2093f4278cd550c303899" in 4.962967974s
  Normal   Killing    2m31s                  kubelet            Container controller failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Created    2m20s (x2 over 3m25s)  kubelet            Created container controller
  Normal   Started    2m20s (x2 over 3m25s)  kubelet            Started container controller
  Normal   Pulled     2m20s                  kubelet            Container image "k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.48.1@sha256:e9fb216ace49dfa4a5983b183067e97496e7a8b307d2093f4278cd550c303899" already present on machine
  Warning  Unhealthy  111s (x9 over 3m11s)   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Warning  Unhealthy  101s (x8 over 3m11s)   kubelet            Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
```

We are using hashicorp/aws -> 3.7.0 and hashicorp/helm -> 2.5.0. Any help with this please. TIA.

Here is my ingress.tf Reference:
https://github.com/easy2stake/thegraph/tree/main/aws-terraform

```
# NGINX Ingress controller used for publishing services deployment

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.thegraph.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.thegraph.certificate_authority.0.data)
    exec {
      api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
      args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", data.aws_eks_cluster.thegraph.name]
      command     = "aws"
    }
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "ingress" {

  repository = var.nginx_ingress_helm_repo_url
  chart      = var.nginx_ingress_helm_chart_name
  version    = var.nginx_ingress_helm_chart_version

  create_namespace = var.k8s_create_namespace
  namespace        = var.k8s_namespace
  name             = var.nginx_ingress_helm_release_name

  set {
    name = "controller.service.annotations.\"service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/aws-load-balancer-type\""
    value = "nlb"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_eks_cluster.thegraph, 
    aws_eks_node_group.thegraph_node_group,
    aws_internet_gateway.thegraph_internet_gw
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Added the reference github repo now.